# Separable metric topology refined with an $F_\sigma$-set

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a separable metrizable space.  Let $A$ be an $F_\sigma$-subset of $X$.  Is the topology generated by $\tau\cup \{A\}$ also metrizable?

Comment: Any thoughts on the question you'd like to add to your post?  Or, could you add the source of the question, and your motivation for asking it?  Could you specify, in your post, what exactly you are unsure of?  Care to share the definition of metrizable space you are working with? (Definitions are your friend, in questions like this.)

Answer (score 2):

No, take $A$ to be the rationals and $\tau$ the standard topology on the reals. It's a standard fact (recall Munkres [$K$-topology](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorff_not_implies_regular) e.g.) that the topology generated by $\tau \cup \{A\}$ is not even regular, let alone metrisable.

Comment: $\tau$ is the standard topology on the reals?

Comment: @aposyndetic yes, I clarified.

Comment: also what if that topology was regular?  Then wouldn't it be metrizable then?

Comment: @aposyndetic For the reals, yes: we'd have a second countable regular space (so   a metrisable one). Regularity is the main obstacle.

Comment: so for instance a space which is a countable union of compact metric spaces would be metrizable?

Comment: oh wait no thats wrong

Comment: @aposyndetic No, not all countable unions of compact metric spaces are metrisable, the example I have is of that form.